# 22.04.2 Driver dependent apps crash even on fresh install

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Ubuntu 22.04.2

My graphics driver wasn’t loading & the key was not registering. Dropped in to Nouveau, removed and purged nvidia including the ppa and did a clean install of the recommended driver. Driver now listed. Still several apps with driver dependencies crash.

```
~/Desktop$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for $user: 
 *-display                 
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3060 Ti Lite Hash Rate]
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:2b:00.0
      version: a1
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
      resources: irq:81 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
 *-graphics
      product: EFI VGA
      physical id: 1
      logical name: /dev/fb0
      capabilities: fb
      configuration: depth=32 resolution=3840,2160
```

```
~/Desktop$ modinfo nvidia
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
firmware:       nvidia/535.86.05/gsp_tu10x.bin
firmware:       nvidia/535.86.05/gsp_ga10x.bin
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        535.86.05
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     1CA09B16AEFD584F1FD78F0
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc06sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        drm
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       5.19.0-50-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         StarDust Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        18:DA:03:D4:64:59:C5:3D:13:C9:7A:31:48:D5:0A:F6:49:66:66:7D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      68:6E:13:09:9F:6B:38:D3:F3:B6:CF:F9:61:59:6F:D3:F0:AC:31:69:
        64:7F:D0:3C:C0:54:4D:B8:21:AF:6F:78:D0:38:9D:CA:02:F3:2E:52:
        C6:10:BA:CB:23:D7:C9:FA:EF:BA:30:96:63:A7:FB:28:A4:8C:50:62:
        2E:7D:D0:94:9B:F9:16:E7:18:4E:A1:48:22:5F:72:AB:6D:64:60:01:
        16:99:A2:C7:CF:19:07:42:7F:23:31:9C:16:2A:17:7E:AC:F6:4C:D9:
        D3:41:BE:06:2D:41:5C:02:E0:F3:A1:22:D1:C6:B7:5E:AA:08:02:9E:
        4B:41:B0:74:1C:45:3E:5F:67:2D:46:02:FA:2F:71:CC:13:AE:E0:D6:
        3E:39:92:94:D4:FE:A4:B9:F0:7D:10:C0:2E:D5:2B:0E:C9:A0:CA:EE:
        6C:E5:4A:71:CE:9A:33:29:DA:80:43:76:FB:FE:9A:89:57:F2:08:B8:
        3E:AC:D5:BD:9A:D9:6D:1F:35:6C:57:D4:EA:63:03:3E:E0:2B:F1:CA:
        9C:00:23:22:E4:05:CC:14:88:87:FB:D3:D9:0C:68:4C:67:66:5F:AA:
        98:3B:60:FC:D4:40:CE:64:67:82:FD:DA:F3:63:FB:8F:4C:1E:21:02:
        B4:41:0E:00:D5:90:0C:A6:53:DA:86:DE:82:FC:F4:CB
parm:           NvSwitchRegDwords:NvSwitch regkey (charp)
parm:           NvSwitchBlacklist:NvSwitchBlacklist=uuid[,uuid...] (charp)
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers:int
parm:           NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableS0ixPowerManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_S0ixPowerManagementVideoMemoryThreshold:int
parm:           NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_DynamicPowerManagementVideoMemoryThreshold:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableGpuFirmware:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableGpuFirmwareLogs:int
parm:           NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_KMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_VMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_NvLinkDisable:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIERelaxedOrderingMode:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterPCIDriver:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableResizableBar:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableDbgBreakpoint:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_GpuBlacklist:charp
parm:           NVreg_TemporaryFilePath:charp
parm:           NVreg_ExcludedGpus:charp
parm:           NVreg_DmaRemapPeerMmio:int
parm:           NVreg_RmNvlinkBandwidth:charp
parm:           rm_firmware_active:charp
```

But gpu-manager.log list several issues.

```
~/Desktop$ cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-535srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-535
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-525srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-525
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-470srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-470
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-450srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-390
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:2489
BusID "PCI:43@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:2b:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 1
Loading nvidia with "no" parameters
Has the system changed? No
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
Takes 1020ms to wait for nvidia udev rules completed.
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

And although this may look like I know what I’m talking about it may help to simplify any answers.

The AskUbuntu Project was my last best hope for an answer.

Comment: Which apps with driver dependencies crash?

Comment: Steam and a few on Lutris